# Parsing wsdl (retrieve namespaces from the definitions)using an Element Tree

Tags: python, wsdl, elementtree, qualified-name

I am trying to parse a wsdl file using ElementTree, As part of this I"d like to retrieve all the namespaces from a  given wsdl definitions element.

For instance in the below snippet , I am trying to retrieve all  the  namespaces in the definitions tag

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="DateService" targetNamespace="http://dev-b.handel-dev.local:8080/DateService.wsdl" xmlns:tns="http://dev-b.handel-dev.local:8080/DateService.wsdl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:myType="DateType_NS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

My code looks like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file='<path_to_my_wsdl>'
tree = xml.parse(xml_file)
rootElement = tree.getroot()
print (rootElement.tag)       #{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions
print(rootElement.attrib)     #targetNamespace="http://dev-b..../DateService.wsdl"
```

As I understand, in ElementTree the namespace URI is combined with the local name of the element .How can I retrieve all the namespace entries from the definitions element?

Appreciate your help on this

P.S: I am new (very!) to python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>>
>>> s = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
... <definitions
...   name="DateService"
...   targetNamespace="http://dev-b.handel-dev.local:8080/DateService.wsdl"
...   xmlns:tns="http://dev-b.handel-dev.local:8080/DateService.wsdl"
...   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
...   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
...   xmlns:myType="DateType_NS"
...   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
...   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
... </definitions>"""
>>> file_ = StringIO(s)
>>> namespaces = []
>>> for event, elem in etree.iterparse(file_, events=('start-ns',)):
...     print elem
...
(u'tns', 'http://dev-b.handel-dev.local:8080/DateService.wsdl')
('', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/')
(u'soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/')
(u'myType', 'DateType_NS')
(u'xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
(u'wsdl', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/')
```

Inspired by the [ElementTree documentation](http://effbot.org/zone/element-qnames.htm)

Comment: Thanks , works like a charm ! my rep does not allow to vote up

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lxml`.

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
namespaces = root.nsmap
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26807636/5375693