# Modifying and rewriting XML file with Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a XML file that starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Recipe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

I need to read it in, modify it, then write it back out. Here is a code snippet:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
with open('base.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

recipe = tree.find('')
t = recipe.find('Targets_Params/Target_Table/Target_Name')
t.text = "new Value"

output_file = open('new.xml', 'w' )
output_file.write(ElementTree.tostring(recipe))
output_file.close()
```

My problem is that when I write the file out I do not get the first line at all, and the second line comes out with just:

```
<Recipe>
```

How I can read in the file, modify it, and write it out while preserving the original structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python ElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree)

Comment: You have namespaces; you need to include the namespace in the tag you are searching for.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that post. My problem is not in getting the tags and contents of the file. My code does that. My issue is when I print it out I don't get the first 2 lines. I had tried many variations of specifying the namespace, but in all cases I was then not able to get the tags. I could brute force it and just read in the first 2 lines directly and then echo them out, but that seems ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: That post suggests using the namespaces argument to find_all() - when I do that I get: TypeError: "findall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespaces'" Then I tried using QName, but with that I cannot find any of the tags in the file.

Comment: I was never able to get this going using ElementTree so I ended up just parsing it myself. Took me less time then I spend messing with ElementTree.