# What is an ElementTree object exactly, and how can I get data from it?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to teach myself how to parse XML. I've read the lxml tutorials, but they're hard to understand. So far, I can do:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml=etree.parse('ham.xml')
>>> xml
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x118de60>
```

But how can I get data from this object? It can't be indexed like `xml[0]`, and it can't be iterated over.

More specifically, I'm using [this xml file](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/shakespeare-dialog-extractor/blob/master/new/ham.xml) and I'm trying to extract, say, everything between the `<l>` tags that's surrounded by `<sp>` tags that contain, say, the `Barnardo` attribute.

Comment: try : `etree.tostring(xml)`

Comment: Great, that works, but how do I get data from a particular tag?

Comment: @Jono: it would be much easier to help you if you showed the contents of `ham.xml`, or at least a sample of it if it is very large.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok. I edited the question to include `ham.xml`.

Comment: Right, that document uses namespaces; see [Parsing XML with namespace in Python ElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14853243)

Comment: You may want to study up on XPath as well, if you want to find that specific a set of elements.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you see; I get `<Element {http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}TEI at 0x10f84f0f0>` instead of `<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x118de60>`. What version of lxml are you using? Moreover, `tree[0]` also gives results. Something appears broken with your setup.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, but whereas most namespaces look like this: `xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"`, the one in my file is just `xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"`, so I don't know what my namespace prefix is supposed to be, so I can't add it to a namespace dictionary.

Comment: @Jono: It's the default namespace. I'll add an example, but your posted session makes me think either `ham.xml` is corrupted or something else is broken with your installation.

Comment: I'm using the ubuntu package `python-lxml` version 3.1.0-1

Comment: @Jono: That should be alright; make sure that `ham.xml` is not empty then. I wrote my answer with lxml 3.2.1 and downloaded `ham.xml` directly from GitHub with the `requests` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [ElementTree `Element` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects).

You can also look at the [lxml API documentation](http://lxml.de/api/index.html), which has an [`lxml.etree._Element` page](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html). That page tells you about every single attribute and method on that class you could ever want to know about.

I'd start with reading the [`lxml.etree` tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html), however.

If the element cannot be indexed, however, it is an empty tag, and there are no child nodes to retrieve.

To find all lines by `Bernardo`, an XPath expression is needed, with a namespace map. It doesn't matter what prefix you use, as long as it is a non-empty string `lxml` will map it to the correct namespace URL:

```
nsmap = {'s': 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'}

for line in tree.xpath('.//s:sp[@who="Barnardo"]/s:l/text()', namespaces=nsmap):
    print line.strip()
```

This extracts all text in `<l>` elements that are contained in `<sp who="Barnardo">` tags. Note the `s:` prefixes on the tag names, the `nsmap` dictionary tells `lxml` what namespace to use. I printed these without the surrounding extra whitespace.

For your sample document, that gives:

```
>>> for line in tree.xpath('.//s:sp[@who="Barnardo"]/s:l/text()', namespaces=nsmap):
...     print line.strip()
... 
Who's there?
Long live the king!
He.
'Tis now struck twelve; get thee to bed, Francisco.
Have you had quiet guard?
Well, good night.
If you do meet Horatio and Marcellus,
The rivals of my watch, bid them make haste.
Say,
What, is Horatio there?
Welcome, Horatio: welcome, good Marcellus.
I have seen nothing.
Sit down awhile;
And let us once again assail your ears,
That are so fortified against our story
What we have two nights seen.
Last night of all,
When yond same star that's westward from the pole
Had made his course to illume that part of heaven
Where now it burns, Marcellus and myself,
The bell then beating one,

In the same figure, like the king that's dead.
Looks 'a not like the king? mark it, Horatio.
It would be spoke to.
See, it stalks away!
How now, Horatio! you tremble and look pale:
Is not this something more than fantasy?
What think you on't?
I think it be no other but e'en so:
Well may it sort that this portentous figure
Comes armed through our watch; so like the king
That was and is the question of these wars.
'Tis here!
It was about to speak, when the cock crew.
```

Comment: That's so awesome, thanks. So I guess I just needed to define an arbitrary namespace ID and then reference that.

Answer (score 2):

One way to parse the XML is using [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).  You can call the `xpath()` member function for an `ElementTree`, in your case `xml`.

As an example, to print the XML for all the `<l>` elements (lines of the play).

```
subtrees = xml.xpath('//l', namespaces={'prefix': 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'})
for l in subtrees:
    print(etree.tostring(l))
```

The [lxml docs](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) detail the xpath functionality.

As pointed out below this doesn't work unless a namespace is specified.  Unfortunately the empty namespace is not supported by `lxml`, but you can change the root node to use a namespace named `prefix`, which is also the name used above.

```
<TEI xmlns:prefix="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="sha-ham">
```

Comment: Except it tells me `subtrees` is empty. I think it's a namespace issue but I don't know where to find my namespace or how to tell lxml what it is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you're correct, my mistake.  Unfortunately the XML file uses the empty namespace, which `lxml` doesn't support.

Comment: @kgraney: Nonsense. `lxml` doesn't support querying with an empty **prefix**. You can pick an arbitrary prefix when searching the tree. See my answer, with working code.