# Is there a key for the default namespace when creating dictionary for use with xml.etree.ElementTree.findall() in Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse an XML document with a default namespace, i.e. the root node has an `xmlns` attribute. This is annoying if you want to try find certain tags in the child nodes because each tag is prefixed with the default namespace.

`xml.etree.ElementTree.findall()` allows for a `namespaces` dictionary to be passed in but I can't seem to find what the default namespace is mapped to. I have tried using 'default', None, 'xmlns' with no success.

One option that does seem to work is to prefix the tag passed to `findall()` with 'xmlns:' (EDIT: this can be any arbitrary unique name actually) and a corresponding entry in the namespaces dictionary but I'm wondering if that is even necessary.

EDIT: I should mention this is Python 3.3.2. I believe in older versions of Python, `findall()` does not accept a `namespaces` argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python ElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree).  (answer appears to be "yes, necessary")

Answer (score 2):

Decided to take a look at the source code for the method. So as it turns out, the following code in xml.etree.ElementPath is doing the dirty work:

```
def xpath_tokenizer(pattern, namespaces=None):
    for token in xpath_tokenizer_re.findall(pattern):
        tag = token[1]
        if tag and tag[0] != "{" and ":" in tag:
            try:
                prefix, uri = tag.split(":", 1)
                if not namespaces:
                    raise KeyError
                yield token[0], "{%s}%s" % (namespaces[prefix], uri)
            except KeyError:
                raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix)
        else:
            yield token
```

`pattern` is the tag passed into `findall()`. If there is no `:` found in the tag, the tokenizer simply returns the tag back without any substitutions.