# Why does this xpath expression return an empty list?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to parse this [XML](http://pastebin.com/Zcw0zrPQ).  It's a YouTube feed.  I'm working based on code in the [tutorial](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method).  I want to get all the `entry` nodes that are nested under the `feed`.

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(text)
entries = root.xpath("/feed/entry")
print entries
```

For some reason `entries` is an empty list.  Why?

Comment: what does "text" look like ?

Comment: It's the XML from the link, read from a file.

Comment: The XML is a mess, can't you indent it properly?

Comment: @NilsWerner I updated the link to point to pretty-printed XML.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as being correct?

Comment: Done.  Thanks for the reminder (and the answer!).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python ElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`feed` and all its children are actually in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace. You need to tell your xpath that:

```
entries = root.xpath("/atom:feed/atom:entry", 
                     namespaces={'atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'})
```

or, if you want to change the default empty namespace:

```
entries = root.xpath("/feed/entry", 
                     namespaces={None: 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'})
```

or, if you don't want to use shorthandles at all:

```
entries = root.xpath("/{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}feed/{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry")
```

To my knowledge the "local namespace" is implicitly assumed for the node you're working with so that operations on children in the same namespace do not require you to set it again. So you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
feed = root.find("/atom:feed",
                     namespaces={'atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'})

title = feed.xpath("title")
entries = feed.xpath("entries")
# etc...
```

Comment: i think you could do it only if your are the author of this XML file to drop this namespace

Comment: You should not "drop the namespace" as there is a reason why Atom feeds are using it. I've added a few more examples that could make your life easier.

Comment: Some XPATH versions allow specifying "*" for any namespace if I recall correctly?

Comment: You can use `*[local-name()='feed']` to match an element `feed` of any namespace. That is considered to be bad practice though.

Comment: @misha Is there any way to avoid specifying the prefix? Yes, use XPath 2.0. But that's not easy from Python.

Comment: @NilsWerner Thank you for your helpful suggestions.  Unfortunately, you can't use `None` for a prefix - lxml specifically prohibits that and raises an exception.  This means that you cannot modify the default namespace.  Also, I tried checking the implicit assumption of the local namespace, but it doesn't work as you describe.  Unless I specify the namespace of each part of the xpath query explicitly, the search returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the namespace in the XML. Here is an explanation: http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html#Conclusion.