# QGIS XML plugin to read and parse second try

Tags: python, xml, parsing, qgis

I try edited code i use last time in plugin to open and parse xml, i still use Element Tree because it integrated in python, this code i edit

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_latih import Ui_latih
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class latihDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_latih()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        cariButton = self.ui.btnCari
        QtCore.QObject.connect(cariButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.cari)

    def cari(self, event=None):

        #open dialog
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')

        self.ui.lineFile.setText(filename)

        #panggil isi data
        self.isiDataFile(filename)

    def isiDataFile(self, nmfile):
        #buka dengan open mode baca
        teksFile = open(nmfile, 'r').read()

        self.ui.textFile.setText(teksFile)

       #parse XML FIle
        self.parsethis(teksFile)

    def parsethis(self, parse):
        element = ETree.fromstring(parse)
        xml_obj = ETree.ElementTree(element)
        for title_obj in xml_obj.findall('.//gco:Integer'):
            self.ui.lineSkala.setText(element)
```

I try change element tree code with different style to see the result

```
def parsethis(self, parse):
        doc =  ETree.fromstring(parse)
        for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/gco:Integer'):
            a=elem.tag, elem.text
            self.ui.lineSkala.setText(a)
```

But this 2 code give me same error message :

```
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISDU~1\apps\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 83, in xpath_tokenizer
    raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix)
SyntaxError: prefix 'gco' not found in prefix map

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Can Someone Help me please?

Comment: You need to pass namespaces: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree

Comment: i try use namespaces but i get error message [ UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment ] , i open a new question thread to ask about this