# ElementTree and finding with NameSpaces

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a valid XHTML file. When I do

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
print ET._namespace_map
```

it lists:

```
'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml': 'html'
```

When I do:

```
root.find('{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}head')
```

it finds:

```
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}head' at 0x104647168>
```

But when I do:

```
root.find('html:head')
```

it complains:

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'html' not found in prefix map
```

Is it possible to find an name-spaced-element with `find` using the syntax `ns:element`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify `namespaces` argument:

```
namespaces = {'html': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'}
root.find('html:head', namespaces=namespaces)
```

Also see:

- [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree)

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks! But what is then the `register_namespace` or `_namespace_map` good for?

Comment: @EcirHana `register_namespace()` is essentially a new way (elementtree>=1.3) of manipulating `_namespace_map`, see what are they good for [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm). Hope that helps.