# Editing XML with Etree and Python

Tags: python, xml, jboss, elementtree

I have a Jboss `host.xml` file that has the effective structure of

```
<host xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.5">
...
    <domain-controller>
       <remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address}" port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}" security-realm="ManagementRealm"/>
    </domain-controller>
...
</host>
```

And am attempting to update the remote host using `Etree` based on the first parameter passed into the script, however using the following code, its not even been able to find the domain-controller stanza

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

newhost=sys.argv[1]

tree = ET.parse('host.xml').getroot()
print len(tree.findall('domain-controller'))
for elem in tree.findall('domain-controller'):
        print elem
    oldhost = elem.find('./remote').text
    print oldhosthost
    oldhost.set('host','newhost')
```

I've been able to find the correct element using `minidom` and `getElementsByTagName`, but would rather work with `Etree` as that seems to be the preferred approach.

Would someone mind telling me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the "preferred approach" nowadays is to use `lxml` since it actually fully supports `XPath` and is stupidly fast to boot.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm limited to what's installed with the default RHEL packaging which I dont believe contains lxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your XML lives in a namespace (`xmlns`), your tags have the be prefixed by the namespace:

```
for elem in tree.findall('{urn:jboss:domain:1.5}domain-controller'):
```

see this thread for alternative addressing of tags in namespaces when using ElementTree: [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-elementtree)