# How do I traverse an XML tree without having to worry about namespace prefixes in Python?

Tags: python, xml

For example, to read an RSS feed, this doesn't work because of the silly {http://purl.org ...} namespaces that get inserted before 'item':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib, urllib.request

url = "http://some/rss/feed"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
xml_text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
xml_root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
for e in xml_root.findall('item'):
  print("I found an item!")
```

Now that findall() has been rendered useless because of the {} prefixes, here's another solution, but this is ugly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib, urllib.request

url = "http://some/rss/feed"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
xml_text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
xml_root = ET.fromstring(xml_text)
for e in xml_root:
  if e.tag.endswith('}item'):
    print("I found an item!")
```

Can I get ElementTree to just trash all the prefixes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle namespaces as clearly explained at:

- [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14853243/771848)

But, what if instead, you'll use a specialized library for reading RSS feeds, like [`feedparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser):

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> url = "http://some/rss/feed"
>>> feed = feedparser.parse(url)
```

---

Though I would personally use an [`XMLFeedSpider` Scrapy spider](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#xmlfeedspider-example). As a bonus, you'll get all other [Scrapy web-scraping framework features](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html).