# XML Python Parsing Namespace

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-namespaces, python-2.5

I have an XML I am trying to parse:

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

new:SumRoot xmlns:ct="link"

xmlns:bo="link"

..new:PolarBear

....new:PolarBear

......new:PolarBearVeb

........new:Donkey>21

........new:Obj

..........bo:Boston

............bo:Number>T6663

..............bo:MarkedAsNumber /

Currently, I have:

```
tree = ET.parse(.xml)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.findall('bo:Number'):
   idea = child.find('Number').text
   print idea
```

And I keep getting "SyntaxError: expected path separator (:)"

Comment: Might the missing angle brackets possibly be causing problems?

Comment: Joking aside, after you fix your XML example, see [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14853243/290085)

Comment: I tried doing that and I got another error saying it can only take 2 arguments and I have 3