# Python - search and replace content in XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a requirement where I have a sample XML file with a well defined structure. I want to search of a tag/child in XML file, replace its text/value with some input file and save the changes to a new XML file preferably without effecting the input sample XML.

I understand this can be achieved by a XML parser to traverse through to the child as intended. But problem is that at the top of my XML file I have something like this

```
<nc:data xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
```

I have written a python function as shown below to do it but I am failing to get the intended thing.

```
def search_replace():
    replicate()        // This function just makes a tmp file from sample input XML to work on. 
    tree = et.parse("/path/to/file/tmp_file.xml")
    tree.find('nc:data/child1/child2/child3').text = 'test'
    tree.write("new_file.xml")
```

Please suggest what would be best approach to handle this. I am not very python-skilled as of now !!

Comment: what is `et` exactly, `xml.etree.ElementTree`?

Comment: Sorry I dint put that.. 

from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Comment: Not actually !!
The link that you have provided speaks of tags with same namespace. My problem is that I have only one namespace but I am unable to traverse through it as it has colon(:) in its name.

Comment: @har07,  I have changed the program and modified it to use lxml. I am pretty much successful but still not complete with it. I want to know how can I get the value attached to a particular tag in xml file. Please share any examples if you have to search and replace in xml file by finding tag in the file. for eg. "<a>abc</a>", here if one can search for 'a' and replace abc inside it

Comment: Then please update your question with the latest code, and explain what you're trying to achieve now

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dictionary that map the prefix to namespace uri and pass that as additional parameter of `find()` :

```
def search_replace():
    replicate()
    tree = et.parse("/path/to/file/tmp_file.xml")
    nsmap = {'nc': 'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0'}
    tree.find('nc:data/child1/child2/child3', nsmap).text = 'test'
    tree.write("new_file.xml")
```