# Parsing a kml file using lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I've got a KML file - I'm using the [wikipedia 'default'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) as a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Placemark>
  <name>New York City</name>
  <description>New York City</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-74.006393,40.714172,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

And I'm trying to extract the coordinates.

Now, I've got a snippet working that embeds the namespace to search:

```
#!/usr/python/python3.4/bin/python3

from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.kml')
root = tree.getroot

print (root.find('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}coordinates').text)
```

This works fine.

However having found this:

[Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree/26807636#26807636)

I'm trying to do it via reading the namespace from the document, using 'root.nsmap'.

```
print (root.nsmap)
```

Gives me:

```
{None: '{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}'}
```

So I think I should be able to do this:

```
print ( root.find('.//coordinates',root.nsmap).text )
```

Or something very similar, using the `None` namespace. (e.g. has no prefix). But this doesn't work - I get an error when doing it:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute  'text'
```

I assume that means that my 'find' didn't find anything in this instance.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This code,

```
root.find('.//coordinates', root.nsmap)
```

does not return anything because no prefix is used. See http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes.

Below are two options that work.

1. Define another nsmap with a real prefix as key:

   ```
   nsmap2 = {"k": root.nsmap[None]}
   print (root.find('.//k:coordinates', nsmap2).text)
   ```
2. Don't bother with prefixes. Put the namespace URI inside curly braces ("Clark notation") to form a universal element name:

   ```
   ns = root.nsmap[None]
   print (root.find('.//{{{0}}}coordinates'.format(ns)).text)
   ```