# Python ElementTree default namespace?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, namespaces, elementtree

Is there a way to define the default/unprefixed namespace in python ElementTree? This doesn't seem to work...

```
ns = {"":"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"}
pom = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("pom.xml")
print(pom.findall("version", ns))
```

Nor does this:

```
ns = {None:"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"}
pom = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("pom.xml")
print(pom.findall("version", ns))
```

This does, but then I have to prefix every element:

```
ns = {"mvn":"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"}
pom = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("pom.xml")
print(pom.findall("mvn:version", ns))
```

Using Python 3.5 on OSX.

EDIT: if the answer is "no", you can still get the bounty :-). I just want a definitive "no" from someone who's spent a lot of time using it.

Comment: Using `ElementTree`, you have to use a prefix. If you use `lxml`, you can use `.nsmap` instead of hard-coding prefixes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree for details

Answer (score 29, accepted):

NOTE: for Python 3.8+ please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62398604/771848).

---

There is no straight-forward way to handle the default namespaces transparently. Assigning the empty namespace a non-empty name is a common solution, as you've already mentioned:

```
ns = {"mvn":"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"}
pom = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse("pom.xml")
print(pom.findall("mvn:version", ns))
```

Note that `lxml.etree` does not allow the use of empty namespaces explicitly. You would get:

> `ValueError`: empty namespace prefix is not supported in ElementPath

---

You can though, make things simpler, by [removing the default namespace definition](http://auxmem.com/2014/07/07/suppressing-the-default-namespace-in-elementtree/) while loading the XML input data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
 
with open("pom.xml") as f:
    xmlstring = f.read()
 
# Remove the default namespace definition (xmlns="http://some/namespace")
xmlstring = re.sub(r'\sxmlns="[^"]+"', '', xmlstring, count=1)
 
pom = ET.fromstring(xmlstring) 
print(pom.findall("version"))
```

Comment: To handle single quotes: `r"""\s(xmlns="[^"]+"|\sxmlns='[^']+')"""`

Comment: To fix @juloo65 answer:
```xmlstring = re.sub(r"""\s(xmlns="[^"]+"|xmlns='[^']+')""", '', xmlstring, count=1)```

Comment: N.B.: "removing the default namespace definition while loading the XML input data" doesn't apply to using `html5lib` to transform HTML-serialization HTML to XHTML.

Comment: This should no longer be the accepted answer as of Python 3.8+. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62398604/6705037

Comment: @delocalizer thanks, added a link to the top of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

ElementTree in Python 3.8 allows empty string as a prefix, so you can declare:

```
ns = {'': 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'}
```

and use that as the second arg in the `find*` methods.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=xml#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the default namespace with:

```py
namespace = pom.getroot().tag.split("}")[0]+"}"
```

Then when you search for elements you add it to your search path:

```py
print(pom.findall(namespace+"version"))
```

Not an elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Doesn't this give you the namespace of the root element?  Which may or may not be the same as the default namespace?

Comment: @J.Beattie You may be correct; I might not use the terms correct.