# extracting result text from xml using Python

Tags: python

I have the following xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:result xmlns:ns2="http://ws.def.com/">
<ns3:value>QWESW12323D2412123S</ns3:value>
</ns3:result>
```

and want to parse it with python and extract this text i tried the following :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
xml = etree.fromstring(data)

item = xml.find('ns3:value')
print item
```

but i get empty item ,could someone help to achieve this with Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Answer (score 0):

Use the syntax '{ns3}value' to apply the namespace - although as ns3 isn't defined, I don't think this is actually valid xml.