# How to parse tiered XML String

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml string that I need to parse in python that looks like this:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <s:Body>
         <PostLoadsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11">
             <PostLoadsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices.Objects" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                 <Errors xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices">
                    <Error>
                         <ErrorMessage>Invalid Location</ErrorMessage>
                    </Error>
                </Errors>
            </PostLoadsResult>
        </PostLoadsResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'
```

I'm having trouble using xmltree to get to the error message of this tree without something like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.fromstring(text).findall('{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body')[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to [handle namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree) and you can do it with `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
tree = ET.fromstring(data)

namespaces = {
    's': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 
    'd': "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices"
}
print(tree.find(".//d:ErrorMessage", namespaces=namespaces).text)
```

Prints `Invalid Location`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the partial [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support):

```
ET.fromstring(text).find('.//{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices}ErrorMessage')
```

That will instruct it to find the first element named `ErrorMessage` with namespace `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices` at any depth.

However, it may be faster to use something like

```
ET.fromstring(text).find('{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body').find('{http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11}PostLoadsResponse').find('{http://webservices.truckstop.com/v11}PostLoadsResult').find('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices}Errors').find('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices}Error').find('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServices}ErrorMessage'
```

If you know your message will always contain those elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getiterator` method on the tree to iterate through the items in it.  You can check the `tag` on each item to see if it's the right one.

```
>>> err = [node.text for node in tree.getiterator() if node.tag.endswith('ErrorMessage')]
>>> err
['Invalid Location']
```