# python3 lxml how to find node when prefix is empty?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

the `word/_rels/document.xml.rels` in a `.docx` file has a empty preifx namespace element: `<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">` which causes a problem that I can't use `findall` mehtod to get the children nodes.

simplified examples:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.fromstring(b'<x><y id="1"/><y id="2"/></x>').findall('y')
[<Element y at 0x382d788>, <Element y at 0x382db48>]
>>> etree.fromstring(b'<x xmlns="wow"><y id="1"/><y id="2"/></x>').findall('y')
[]
# How to find these children nodes like previous one?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the same as [using the built-in `xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree), plus another option if you use `lxml`'s `xpath()` method :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring(b'<x xmlns="wow"><y id="1"/><y id="2"/></x>')

>>> root.findall('{wow}y')
[<Element {wow}y at 0x2b489c8>, <Element {wow}y at 0x2b48588>]

>>> ns = {'d': 'wow'}
>>> root.findall('d:y', ns)
[<Element {wow}y at 0x2b489c8>, <Element {wow}y at 0x2b48588>]
>>> root.xpath('d:y', namespaces=ns)
[<Element {wow}y at 0x2b489c8>, <Element {wow}y at 0x2b48588>]
```

Notice that descendant elements without prefix inherits ancestor's default namespace *implicitly*, that's why you need to consider the namespace when selecting `<y>` despite the namespace was declared at the parent element `<x>`.