# How do I Parse XML value with Python 2.7

Tags: xml, python-2.7, parsing, xml-parsing

API Request: http://iss.ndl.go.jp/api/opensearch?isbn=9784334770051

I need to get one specific value from the XML that provided through API from the above.
I try to get the all value from the `<item>` and also the `<dc:title>`'s value specifically 
Following are my current code that I were attempt to get all value from items but didn't work.

```
import codecs
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import re, pprint
from xml.etree.ElementTree import *
import csv
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 errorCheck = "0"
isbn = raw_input("Enter IBSN Number Please ")
isIsbn = len(isbn)


if isIsbn == 10 or isIsbn == 13:
    errorCheck = 1;

    url = "http://iss.ndl.go.jp/api/opensearch?isbn=%s" % isbn
    req = urllib2.Request(url)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    XmlData = response.read()
    root = ET.fromstring(XmlData)

    print(root.tag,root.attrib)

    for child in root.find('item'):
        print child.tag
        print child.attrib
        print child.text

if errorCheck == "0":
    print "It is not ISBN"
```

Comment: Element tree but require all key are  unique ! Parse as string, cos more XML files haven't full quality data pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<item>` is not direct child of the root element so you can't find it by mentioning the element directly (`root.find('item')`). You can use `.//item` to find `item` element anywhere within the root :

```
for child in root.find('.//item'):
```

or specify the exact path from root to `<item>` :

```
for child in root.find('channel/item'):
```

As for finding `<dc:title>` element, see : [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Comment: THANKS`! I'l try it!

Comment: namespaces = {'dc': root} # add more as needed
 print root.findall('dc:title', namespaces)

I currently trying but I assume I'm not understanding the link you have provided.
The code you give me work fine.
What I need to with parsing the ElementTree?

Comment: @KeiroKamioka Add `.//` at the beginning, for the reason I have mentioned in this answer : `root.findall('.//dc:title', namespaces)`

Comment: @KeiroKamioka Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem in question : [more about accepting answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Did I accept answer? I'm very new to asking question here and not sure I did it correctly.
I were only using asking question as substitue for my friend who does not understand English.