# Access XML element by name

Tags: python, xml

[image]

Im using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse my XML data. I'm trying to get the text value of `<Name>`

This is my code.

```
for Content in Zone[0]:
    print(Content.find('Name').text)
```

It is returning as NoneObject

However, I am able to access the Element using

```
for Content in Zone[0]:
    print(Content[12].text)
```

I think I might have found the problem as when I print the tags out, it doesn't display `Name` and instead it displays `{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/}Name`. What is the extra data infront of the tag name?

Comment: Can you please add the XML content as a code block, not as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is likely has default namespace -namespace declared with no prefix-. Notice that descendant elements without prefix inherits default namespace implicitly. You can handle default namespace the way you would [handle prefixed namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree); just map a prefix to the namespace URI, and use that prefix along with element name to reference element in namespace :

```
namespaces = {'d': 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/'}
for Content in Zone[0]:
    print(Content.find('d:Name', namespaces).text)
```