# SyntaxError: prefix 'a' not found in prefix map

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

I'm trying to create a function which counts words in `pptx` document. The problem is that I can't figure out how to find only this kind of tags:

`<a:t>Some Text</a:t>`

When I try to: `print xmlTree.findall('.//a:t')`, it returns

> SyntaxError: prefix 'a' not found in prefix map

Do you know what to do to make it work?

This is the function:

```
def get_pptx_word_count(filename):
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import zipfile
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    i=0
    wordcount = 0
    while True:
        i+=1
        slidename = 'slide{}.xml'.format(i)
        try:
            slide = z.read("ppt/slides/{}".format(slidename))
        except KeyError:
            break
        xmlTree = ET.fromstring(slide)
        for elem in xmlTree.iter(): 
            if elem.tag=='a:t':
                #text = elem.getText
                #num = len(text.split(' '))
                #wordcount+=num
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to tell `ElementTree` about your XML namespaces.

References:

- *Official Documentation (Python 2.7):* [19.7.1.6. Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces)
- *Existing answer on StackOverflow:* [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/1172714)
- *Article by the author of ElementTree:* [ElementTree: Working with Namespaces and Qualified Names](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm)

Comment: Link only answers aren't particularly helpful. Any relevant information to solving this problem should be included in the answer itself.

Answer (score 13):

The way to specify the namespace inside ElementTree is:

```
{namespace}element
```

So, you should change your query to:

```
print xmlTree.findall('.//{a}t')
```

Edit:

As @mxjn pointed out if a is a prefix and not the URI you need to insert the URI instead of a:

```
 print xmlTree.findall('.//{http://tempuri.org/name_space_of_a}t')
```

or you can supply a prefix map:

```
 prefix_map = {"a": "http://tempuri.org/name_space_of_a"}
 print xmlTree.findall('.//a:t', prefix_map)
```

Comment: This won't work. `a` is a prefix, not the actual namespace URI.