# Element.Tree write file with the existing namespaces (

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree

XML file to be changed

```


```
loaded with elementree ET.parse -> find-> element.text = change -> tree.write
filled without use of namespaces; tree.write(output, encoding=utf-8)->:
```

0
```

I loose the xs:element detail?

i have tried with ET.Namespaces, namespaces(xs:"url w3") but than cannot root.find(.//xs:name/, namespaces=namespaces) the right element.

[SyntaxError: prefix 'a' not found in prefix map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772297/syntaxerror-prefix-a-not-found-in-prefix-map)
[is there a way to see all the existing namespaces in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71067811/is-there-a-way-to-see-all-the-existing-namespaces-in-python)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with well-formed XML and complete Python code.

Comment: have you tried passing `xml_declaration=True` to `tree.write` ?

Comment: Yes, also included method="xml" no change also