# XPath: Find all known tags with specific attribute

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I want to get a list of all `trololo` tags with `attr` attribute (but not `xxx` or any other) using Python from following XML:

```
<data>
    <test>
        <trololo attr="1">
        </trololo>
    </test>
    <test>
        <trololo>
        </trololo>
    </test>
    <test>
        <trololo attr="X">
        </trololo>
    </test>
    <test>
        <xxx attr="Y">
        </xxx>
    </test>
</data>
```

I've tried using `//*[@attr]`, but result includes `xxx` tag as well. All other variations I tried are failing so far.

The actual Python code I'm using:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pprint import pprint

tree  = ET.parse('test.xml')
nodes = tree.findall('//*trololo[@attr]')

pprint(nodes)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

UPDATE:

I've found out this was a namespace problem, which makes this question a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree). The problem was I had a root node looking like this:

```
<data xmlns="http://example.com">
```

Comment: Please note, I'm not aware of actual depth of the `<trololo>` nodes. They might be 100 levels below the *root*.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I have run the same from my terminal, and I got the output `[<Element 'trololo' at 0x7fab55c90ef8>, <Element 'trololo' at 0x7fab55c903b8>]`

Comment: @FarhanK I'm using Python 3.

Comment: `nodes = tree.findall('//trololo[@attr]')` i.e without `*`?

Comment: @har07 it works for me with or withoutu the `*`

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Your code works fine for me on both python 2 and 3. Maybe there is something wrong with your xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### All elements by name with a named attribute

As [@har07 correctly answers in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327219/xpath-find-all-known-tags-with-specific-attribute#comment81605665_47327219), the XPath

```
//trololo[@attr]
```

will select all `trololo` elements with an `attr` attribute (regardless of its value), as requested.

This string,

```
//*trololo[@attr]
```

is syntactically not an XPath expression at all but does resemble,

```
//*:trololo[@attr]
```

which is syntactically invalid under XPath 2.0 (but not XPath 1.0).  It says to select `trololol` elements in any namespace.  To disregard namespaces in XPath 1.0  ([but you really shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40796315/290085)), use `local-name()`:

```
//*[local-name() = 'trololo' and @attr]
```

### Other variations

- *All elements with a named attribute:* `//*[@attr]`
- *All elements with any attribute:* `//*[@*]`

Comment: I've found out this was indeed namespace problem. Thanks!