# problems with parsing namespace XML. Showing null. in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, xml-namespaces

My XML file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EMJSbT7iGLFyFTFP0vKmOuKssqKGYF9v/view?usp=sharing). Though I am able to get the root node and its child nodes from this file. But, I am not able to get the one that I need. I want to get the content of  `<ce:section-title>Methods</ce:section-title>`
I have tried both xml and lxml package.

When I use the following,

```
 tree = lxml.etree.parse(fname) #fname is xml filename
 root= tree.getroot()

print(root[5].findall("ce:section-title",root.nsmap)
```

It just gives me null [] bracket. It gives the same null bracket when I use the following command:

```
for item in tree.iter('{http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ja/dtd}ce:section-title'):
    print(item)
```

I did try to solve with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree), but I am getting the following error on this code:

```
ns = {"ce":"http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd"}
print(root.findall("ce:title", ns).text)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Any direction will be helpfull

Comment: Your posted code is using variables (`root`, `tree`) which you have not provided definitions for.

Comment: sorry,, thanks,, included

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `findall(.//ce:section-title, root.nsmap)`.

With `.//` prepended, you are searching for `section-title` descendants at all levels below the context node. With `findall(ce:section-title, root.nsmap)`, only direct child elements can be located.

Example:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("data.xml")  # Your XML
root = tree.getroot()

for e in root.findall(".//ce:section-title", root.nsmap):
    print(e.text)
```

Output:

```
Abstract
Keywords
Introduction
Materials and methods
Results
The appearing species by taxon
List of regional appearing species
Discussion
Acknowledgments
References
```