# python elementTree get attribute that ends with

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

giving the following xml as input to elementTree (using python 2.7):

```
 <body>
<div region="imageRegion" xml:id="img_SUB6756004155_0" ttm:role="caption" smpte:backgroundImage="#SUB6756004155_0">
</body>
```

i get this attributes:
[image]

so i need to find the attribute the ends with 'backgroundImage' or 'id'

normally i would do it like this:

```
 div.get('region')
```

but here i only know part of the attribute name,

is it possible to use regex?

Comment: Read [parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Comment: @mzjn the div has an end tag '>' and beside, that's not the point

Comment: but it is XML..

Comment: @stovfl i read that, but if i understand correctly i need to know the namespace and define it before, what if i don't know it (or it could change) can i find an attribute with only part of the string?

Comment: @OrtalTurgeman: *"if i don't know it"*: Read the last sentence in the Answer of [parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/7414759)

Comment: if you mean to use lxml, i can't use it, it doesn't exist by default (probably needs installation) and i need something that will work on every machine with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to iterate over the attributes and return the value of the attribute with a local-name that ends in `backgroundImage`.

Example...

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

XML = '''
<body xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" 
      xmlns:smpte="http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2052-1/2013/smpte-tt">
  <div region="imageRegion" xml:id="img_SUB6756004155_0" 
       ttm:role="caption" smpte:backgroundImage="#SUB6756004155_0"></div>
</body>'''

root = ET.fromstring(XML)
div = root.find("div")
val = next((v for k, v in div.attrib.items() if k.endswith('backgroundImage')), None)

if val:
    print(f"Value: {val}")
```

Outputs...

```
Value: #SUB6756004155_0
```

This can be fragile though. It only returns the first attribute found.

If that's a problem, maybe use a list instead:

```py
val = [v for k, v in div.attrib.items() if k.endswith('backgroundImage')]
```

It would also incorrectly return an attribute that ends with "backgroundImage" (like "invalid_backgroundImage").

If that's a problem, maybe use regex instead:

```py
val = next((v for k, v in div.attrib.items() if re.match(r".*}backgroundImage$", "}" + k)), None)
```

If you're ever able to switch to lxml, the testing of the local-name can be done in xpath...

```py
val = div.xpath("@*[local-name()='backgroundImage']")
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below demonstrates how you can get the value of the `smpte:backgroundImage` attribute from a well-formed XML document (the input document in the question is not well-formed).

`smpte:` means that the attribute is bound to a namespace, which is `http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2052-1/2013/smpte-tt`, judging by the screenshot. Note that both the `ttm` and `smpte` prefixes must be declared in the XML document (`xmlns:ttm="..."` and `xmlns:smpte="..."`).

In the `get()` call, the attribute name must be given in ["Clark notation"](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm#element-tree-representation): `{http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2052-1/2013/smpte-tt}backgroundImage`.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

XML = '''
<body xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" 
      xmlns:smpte="http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2052-1/2013/smpte-tt">
  <div region="imageRegion" xml:id="img_SUB6756004155_0" 
       ttm:role="caption" smpte:backgroundImage="#SUB6756004155_0"></div>
</body>'''

root = ET.fromstring(XML)
div = root.find("div")
print(div.get("{http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2052-1/2013/smpte-tt}backgroundImage"))
```

Output:

```
#SUB6756004155_0
```

Comment: but this `http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2052-1/2013/smpte-tt` could change, it's not  hard coded

Answer (score 0):

this solution also worked for me:

```
r = re.compile(r'img_.+')
image_id = filter(r.match, div.attrib.values())
id = image_id[0].split('_', 1)[1]
```

id ='SUB6756004155_0'