# Whats the most efficient way to parse this XML sitemap with Python?

Tags: python, xml, sitemap

I have the following sitemap that I am trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url> 
      <loc>https://www.example.com/examplea</loc> 
      <priority>0.5</priority> 
      <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
   <url> 
     <loc>https://www.example.com/exampleb</loc> 
     <priority>0.5</priority> 
     <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
</urlset>
```

Whats the fastest way to obtain the url links within the loc tags using Python?

I tried using ElementTree, but I think it didnt work because of namespaces.

I need to get "https://www.example.com/examplea" and "https://www.example.com/exampleab"

Comment: If your xml file structure is stable, regex is good enough for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

str = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url> 
      <loc>https://www.example.com/examplea</loc> 
      <priority>0.5</priority> 
      <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
   <url> 
     <loc>https://www.example.com/exampleb</loc> 
     <priority>0.5</priority> 
     <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
</urlset>
"""  
url = re.findall("<loc>(.*?)</loc>", str)
```

Comment: Excellent. If you can, rewrite the string as a multiline string by placing it between `'''` and `'''` so it is easier to see

Comment: Like @Clarmy Lee did in his answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use regular expression.

For your example, your demand can be met by code as follow:

```py
import re

string = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url> 
      <loc>https://www.example.com/examplea</loc> 
      <priority>0.5</priority> 
      <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
   <url> 
     <loc>https://www.example.com/exampleb</loc> 
     <priority>0.5</priority> 
     <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
</urlset>
'''

pattern = '(?<=<loc>)[a-zA-z]+://[^\s]*(?=</loc>)'

re.findall(pattern,string)
```

The result is `['https://www.example.com/examplea', 'https://www.example.com/exampleb']`

Comment: You should really have it depend on the `<loc>` and `</loc>` tags. If other bits of information appear with URLs, that will be captured in your regex

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. I changed my pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers said, you can use regex. But if you are a bit uncomfortable in using regular expressions, you can also use xmltodict module in python which converts the xml into a dictionary, and you can easily obtain any kind of data you need from the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML but bypassing namespace

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url> 
      <loc>https://www.example.com/examplea</loc> 
      <priority>0.5</priority> 
      <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
   <url> 
     <loc>https://www.example.com/exampleb</loc> 
     <priority>0.5</priority> 
     <lastmod>2019-03-14</lastmod> 
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq> 
   </url> 
</urlset>'''

it = ET.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
for _, el in it:
    if '}' in el.tag:
        el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
    for at in el.attrib.keys(): # strip namespaces of attributes too
        if '}' in at:
            newat = at.split('}', 1)[1]
            el.attrib[newat] = el.attrib[at]
            del el.attrib[at]
root = it.root

urls = [u.text for u in root.findall('.//loc')]
print(urls)
```

Output

```
['https://www.example.com/examplea', 'https://www.example.com/exampleb']
```