# How to read this XML file in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to read some xml data for a project, but It just won't work... I have this code (used xml file is shown below):

```
import time
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
ET.register_namespace('', "http://bison.connekt.nl/tmi8/kv6/msg")

while True:
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    tree = ET.parse("RET.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root)
    for debug in root.findall(".//"): 
        print(debug.text)
    for line in root.findall('.Version'):
    print(line.text)
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    time.sleep(5)
```

It successfully finds the contents of all elements, but when I search for a specific element like 'Version' it won't return any content. This is the current output:

---

```
<Element '{http://bison.connekt.nl/tmi8/kv6/msg}VV_TM_PUSH' at 0x03D775A0>

RET

BISON 8.1.1.0
KV6posinfo
2020-12-04T21:22:56.1275145+01:00
ttt

RET
M007

2020-12-04

200180

0

HA8215

0

2020-12-04T21:22:56.1119143+01:00

SERVER

0
-920

--------------------------------------------
```

And this is the used XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VV_TM_PUSH xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://bison.connekt.nl/tmi8/kv6/msg">
<SubscriberID>
RET</SubscriberID><Version>
BISON 8.1.1.0</Version>
<DossierName>KV6posinfo</DossierName>
<Timestamp>2020-12-04T21:22:56.1275145+01:00</Timestamp>
<KV6posinfo>ttt
<ONSTOP>
<dataownercode>RET</dataownercode>
<lineplanningnumber>M007</lineplanningnumber>
<operatingday>2020-12-04</operatingday>
<journeynumber>200180</journeynumber>
<reinforcementnumber>0</reinforcementnumber>
<userstopcode>HA8215</userstopcode>
<passagesequencenumber>0</passagesequencenumber>
<timestamp>2020-12-04T21:22:56.1119143+01:00</timestamp>
<source>SERVER</source>
<vehiclenumber>0</vehiclenumber>
<punctuality>-920</punctuality>
</ONSTOP>
</KV6posinfo>
</VV_TM_PUSH>
```

I added 'ttt' in the  tag, for testing purposes.

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/5386938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 flaws in your code:

1. In line `for line in root.findall('.Version'):` there is unnecessary dot.
   Note that *Version* is a direct descenant of the root element, so it
   is enough to put just the tag name (actually not only, details later).
2. Line `print(line.text)` is not indented, so actually you should have
   received a compilation error.

An now how to properly work with **namespaced** XML:

Note that your input file contains a default namespace
(*http://bison.connekt.nl/tmi8/kv6/msg*)

Then if you want to refer to any element in this namespace, you have to:

- define a namespace dictionary (key - prefix, value - URI), in your
  case only one "prefix:URI" pair,
- precede the tag name with the namespace prefix and a colon,
- pass the namespace dictionary as the second argument to e.g. *findall*.

So in your case replace the respective code fragment with:

```
ns = {'bis': 'http://bison.connekt.nl/tmi8/kv6/msg'}
for line in root.findall('bis:Version', ns):
    print(f'Version: {line.text}')
```

I added *Version:* to indicate what has been printed.

Consider also printing *line.text.strip()*, because your tag has a leading
*NewLine*.