# How to retrieve the src attribute from an xml using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-xmlschema

Hi I am using a small python program to search for all the  tag from an xml. after accessing the  tag i want to access all the src attribute. How can i do this in python. the following is my xml definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<smil systemRequired="pss6"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language"
    xmlns:pss6="http://www.3gpp.org/SMIL20/PSS6/">
    <head>
        <meta id="meta-smil1.0-a" name="Publisher" content="OMA"/>
        <layout>
            <root-layout width="100%" height="100%"/>
            <region id="UP" top="0%" left="0%" height="50%" width="100%" fit="meet" backgroundColor="white"/>
            <region id="DOWN" top="50%" left="0%" height="50%" width="100%" fit="meet" backgroundColor="white"/>
            <region id="FULL" top="0%" left="0%" height="100%" width="100%" fit="meet" backgroundColor="white"/>
        </layout>
    </head>
    <body>
        <par index="0" dur="10" size="3326">
            <img src="f5d226a7-487f-4038-8051-d9382acde16f" region="DOWN" fill="freeze" size="3310"/>
            <text src="tess" region="UP" size="16"/>
        </par>
        <par index="1" dur="10" size="19534">
            <img src="7556e55d-52c7-4807-9034-d6abee06ce67" region="DOWN" fill="freeze" size="2796"/>
            <text src="bigno" region="UP" size="20"/>
            <audio src="84620751-25db-4db9-b361-43a3dfd70f21" size="16718"/>
        </par>
    </body>
</smil>
```

the following is my python program.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse():
    tree = ET.parse('smil.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for img in root.findall('./body/par/img'):
        print(img)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```

what i want is to retreive all the img tags, then retrieves the src attribute and store the attribute values in a list .

so the output i expect is a list = [f5d226a7-487f-4038-8051-d9382acde16f,7556e55d-52c7-4807-9034-d6abee06ce67 ]  because in the xml we have two  tags .

How can i achieve it ?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree) of the element in your path.

```py
def parse():
    tree = ET.parse('smil.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    ns = {"x": "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language"}
    for img in root.findall('.//x:img', namespaces=ns):
        print(img.attrib['src'])
```

However if you are familiar with XPath, I would suggest looking into [lxml](https://lxml.de/) for parsing XML and HTML.