# Access Specific Tag Attributes in XML with No Namespace Prefix

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML. (Attribute Names are changed because of Privacy reasons)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
  <edmx:Reference Uri="https://someURL.xml">
    <edmx:Include Alias="Common" Namespace="com.sss.vocab.Common.v1"/>
  </edmx:Reference>
  <edmx:Reference Uri="https://oasis-tcs.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/Org.OData.Core.V1.xml">
    <edmx:Include Alias="Core" Namespace="Org.OData.Core.V1"/>
  </edmx:Reference>
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="MechanicalTechnicalService" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="EntityContainer">
        <EntitySet Name="Cars" EntityType="MechanicalTechnicalService.Cars">
        </EntitySet>
        <EntitySet Name="Plane" EntityType="MechanicalTechnicalService.Plane">
        </EntitySet>
        <EntitySet Name="Ships" EntityType="MechanicalTechnicalService.Ships"/>
        <EntitySet Name="Customer" EntityType="MechanicalTechnicalService.Customer"/>
        <EntitySet Name="Letter" EntityType="MechanicalTechnicalService.Letter"/>
        <EntitySet Name="Farm" EntityType="MechanicalTechnicalService.Farm">
        </EntitySet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

I want to access the Name Attribute of all EntitySets but i dont get any response. I am aware that namespaces have to be considered. I tried something like this:

```
namespace = {'edm' : 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm'}
print(root.findall('edm:EntitySet',namespace))
```

Here I dont get any response. But when using this:

```
namespace = {'edmx' : 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx'}
print(root.findall('edmx:Reference',namespace))
```

I have access to the element. I am aware of the discussion here: [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

But in my case the solutions proposed here were not successfull. I just want to access all EntitySet tags in this XML document and save their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Try:

```
for n in root.findall('.//edm:EntitySet',namespace):
    print(n.attrib["Name"])
```

Or, if you have the current version of python, you can use wildcards for namespaces:

```
for n in root.findall('.//{*}EntitySet'):
    print(n.attrib["Name"])
```

In either case, the output should be

```
Cars
Plane
Ships
Customer
Letter
Farm
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I was very frustrated because I thought logically I am doing everything right. Could you explain why you need './/edm:EntitySet' to get access to the tag? Why is edm:EntitySet in this case not enough?

Comment: @TheCodingKing Elementtree doesn't like absolute paths, so it prefers you start with the root `(.)` and go from there. Things are somewhat simpler if you can use lxml instead of elementree.