# Python 2.7 ElementTree find() using multiple namespaces

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I unable to write xpath to find Element due to presence of multiple namespace.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mapping xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.asam.net/XILAPI/Mapping/1.0">
  <FrameworkLabelList>
    <FrameworkLabel Id="Hazard_Switch" Type="StringVariable">
      <CustomProperties />
    </FrameworkLabel>
  </FrameworkLabelList>
  <TestbenchLabelList PortId="">
    <TestbenchLabel Id="BdyChassIO_slave/Model Root/BCM/Exterior_Lamp/HZS_CN4_Pin02_PHY/Control/Value">
      <TestbenchSimpleType Type="StringValue" />
    </TestbenchLabel>
  </TestbenchLabelList>
  <MappingTable>
    <RasterMappingList>
      <RasterMapping PortId="" FrameworkRasterName="" TestbenchRasterName="" />
    </RasterMappingList>
    <LabelMappingList>
      <LabelMapping>
        <TestbenchLabelReference LabelId="BdyChassIO_slave/Model Root/BCM/Exterior_Lamp/HZS_CN4_Pin02_PHY/Control/Value" PortId="">
          <FromSimple>
            <OneToOne />
          </FromSimple>
        </TestbenchLabelReference>
        <FrameworkLabelReference LabelId="Hazard_Switch" />
      </LabelMapping>
    </LabelMappingList>
    <StringMappingList>
      <StringMappingGroup PortId="">
        <StringMapping FrameworkString="" TestbenchString="" />
      </StringMappingGroup>
    </StringMappingList>
  </MappingTable>
</Mapping>
```

I know how to write xpath or simple path to findout particular Element from XML.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
file_path = r'D:\Dummy\Test.xml'
namespaces = {}
def register_all_namespaces(filename):
            global namespaces
            # get namespace from xml file
            namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse(filename, events=['start-ns'])])
            #register namespace
            for ns in namespaces:
                ET.register_namespace(ns, namespaces[ns])
                print ns
                
register_all_namespaces(file_path)  
tree = ET.parse(file_path)
root = tree.getroot() 
fwl =  root.find('xsd/FrameworkLabelList/FrameworkLabel',namespaces)
print(fwl)
```

I want to know how to write xpath to find out "FrameworkLabel" tag.

Comment: The only namespace that is actually used is `http://www.asam.net/XILAPI/Mapping/1.0` (the default namespace).

Comment: @mzjn Can you provide syntax to write inside find function

Comment: @mzjn I am using python 2.7

Comment: I am working on framework which was created on 2.7

Comment: `root.find('.//{http://www.asam.net/XILAPI/Mapping/1.0}FrameworkLabel')` should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/407651, https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: @mzjn it's working ...thanks for help