# How to parse XML with Python ElementTree when there is a colon in the namespace

Tags: python-3.x

I have the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree/14853417#14853417), but I struggle to get it working.

I want to get all the values of `<itunes:subtitle>`. Not to be confused with the self-closing tag `<itunes:subtitle/>`.

This is my XML data in `sample.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <title>A title</title>
      <itunes:subtitle/>
      <itunes:subtitle>A subtitle</itunes:subtitle>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[Another title]]></title>
      <itunes:subtitle/>
      <itunes:subtitle>Yet another subtitlen</itunes:subtitle>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('sample.xml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

for xml_item in root.iter('item'):
    namespaces = {'itunes': 'subtitle'}
    print(root.findall('itunes:subtitle', namespaces))
```

However, this returns empty lists.

```
[]
[]
```

I could not find any meaningful help in the other 9-year-old question or elsewhere on Stackoverflow. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the namespaces declared in the `<rss>` element:

```
<rss version="2.0"
  xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
  xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
```

The alias `itunes` refers to the namespace `http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd`, and the alias `content` refers to the namespace `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/`.

In your Python code, the `namespaces` dictionary needs to reflect those mappings, so:

```
namespaces = {'itunes': 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'}
```

Second, from [the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements):

> `Element.findall()` finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element.

In your loop...

```
for xml_item in root.iter('item'):
    print(root.findall('itunes:subtitle', namespaces))
```

...your loop variable is `xml_item`, but you're calling `findall` on `root` -- and your `<itunes:subtitle>` elements are not direct children of the `rss` tag. You need:

```
for xml_item in root.iter('item'):
    print(xml_item.findall('itunes:subtitle', namespaces))
```

Given us:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open('sample.xml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {'itunes': 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'}

for xml_item in root.iter('item'):
    print(xml_item.findall('itunes:subtitle', namespaces))
```

Running the above code produces:

```
[<Element '{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}subtitle' at 0x7fb46ab48770>, <Element '{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}subtitle' at 0x7fb46ab487c0>]
[<Element '{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}subtitle' at 0x7fb46ab488b0>, <Element '{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}subtitle' at 0x7fb46ab48900>]
```

Comment: This is a much more elaborate answer than what I could find. Thanks. Although you seem to have missed out on how to exclude the self-closing tags. Perhaps another question, that is.

Comment: "Although you seem to have missed out on how to exclude the self-closing tags." No, I intentionally left that out.
Don't think of them as "self-closing tags"; think of them as "empty tags". You can exclude them by checking to see if they have any content (e.g., check for `element.text`).