# Parsing and extracting from XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to get the "ProductDescription" to a list, that is inside of the following XML file.
For that, this is the path that I need to follow: AuditFile/SourceDocuments/SalesInvoices/Invoice/Line/ProductDescription.

[image]
[image]

The problem is that there are several "Invoices", from which I want to extract the "ProductDescription" from.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuditFile xmlns="urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Tax:PT_1.04_01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <AuditFileVersion>1.04_01</AuditFileVersion>
        <ProductVersion>23.183.765</ProductVersion>
    </Header>
    <MasterFiles>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <CustomerID>51</CustomerID>
            <AccountID>Desconhecido</AccountID>
            <CustomerTaxID>99999999</CustomerTaxID>
            <CompanyName>Consumidor Final</CompanyName>
            <BillingAddress>
                <AddressDetail>Desconhecido</AddressDetail>
                <City>Desconhecido</City>
                <PostalCode>Desconhecido</PostalCode>
                <Country>PT</Country>
            </BillingAddress>
            <SelfBillingIndicator>0</SelfBillingIndicator>
        </Customer>
        <Product>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <ProductCode>10</ProductCode>
            <ProductGroup>FAMILIA017</ProductGroup>
            <ProductDescription>SOLERO ABACAXI</ProductDescription>
            <ProductNumberCode>10</ProductNumberCode>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProductType>S</ProductType>
            <ProductCode>100</ProductCode>
            <ProductGroup>FAMILIA001</ProductGroup>
            <ProductDescription>CAFE</ProductDescription>
            <ProductNumberCode>100</ProductNumberCode>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <ProductType>P</ProductType>
            <ProductCode>9</ProductCode>
            <ProductGroup>FAMILIA017</ProductGroup>
            <ProductDescription>PICOLERO</ProductDescription>
            <ProductNumberCode>9</ProductNumberCode>
        </Product>
        <TaxTable>
            <TaxTableEntry>
                <TaxType>IVA</TaxType>
                <TaxCountryRegion>PT</TaxCountryRegion>
                <TaxCode>INT</TaxCode>
                <Description>13% - INT</Description>
                <TaxPercentage>13</TaxPercentage>
            </TaxTableEntry>
            <TaxTableEntry>
                <TaxType>IVA</TaxType>
                <TaxCountryRegion>PT</TaxCountryRegion>
                <TaxCode>NOR</TaxCode>
                <Description>23% - NOR</Description>
                <TaxPercentage>23</TaxPercentage>
            </TaxTableEntry>
        </TaxTable>
    </MasterFiles>
    <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
            <NumberOfEntries>100</NumberOfEntries>
            <TotalDebit>0.00</TotalDebit>
            <TotalCredit>737.29</TotalCredit>
            <Invoice>
                <InvoiceNo>FSC B/3872</InvoiceNo>
                <ATCUD>JFPNP73W-3872</ATCUD>
                <DocumentStatus>
                    <InvoiceStatus>N</InvoiceStatus>
                    <InvoiceStatusDate>2023-10-01T13:08:50</InvoiceStatusDate>
                    <SourceID>Admin</SourceID>
                    <SourceBilling>P</SourceBilling>
                </DocumentStatus>
                <Hash>mHDyTw5LNdmn6263g+tPlDSoawQ77ZfHFXka03kKNQx5h9jo5GYCLXVMcoIlktllJ8xSByhkQsyFLk/0mKy3e5tu/PqoPktCV4kGclFcFeC8MueTICaCA+wVH2mPtLRD2eKjaS3+AcuqYrbJAYYTeG85L5kuWNVbqxWwlVJBpMw=</Hash>
                <HashControl>1</HashControl>
                <InvoiceDate>2023-10-01</InvoiceDate>
                <InvoiceType>FS</InvoiceType>
                <SpecialRegimes>
                    <SelfBillingIndicator>0</SelfBillingIndicator>
                    <CashVATSchemeIndicator>0</CashVATSchemeIndicator>
                    <ThirdPartiesBillingIndicator>0</ThirdPartiesBillingIndicator>
                </SpecialRegimes>
                <SourceID>Admin</SourceID>
                <SystemEntryDate>2023-10-01T13:08:50</SystemEntryDate>
                <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
                <Line>
                    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                    <ProductCode>18</ProductCode>
                    <ProductDescription>Cachorro</ProductDescription>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>UN</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <UnitPrice>4.8780</UnitPrice>
                    <TaxPointDate>2023-10-01</TaxPointDate>
                    <Description>Cachorro</Description>
                    <CreditAmount>4.878049</CreditAmount>
                    <Tax>
                        <TaxType>IVA</TaxType>
                        <TaxCountryRegion>PT</TaxCountryRegion>
                        <TaxCode>NOR</TaxCode>
                        <TaxPercentage>23</TaxPercentage>
                    </Tax>
```

I tried this but the output is none.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Parse XML into a Element Tree
tree= ET.parse ("2023_10_2023.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for source in root.findall('Invoice'):
    for source1 in source.findall('Line'):
        for source2 in source1.findall('ProductDescription'):
            print(source2.text)
```

Can some one help me, to get a list of the ProductDescription ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share a valid xml example. Your xml contains failures.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are skipping over nodes. Per [the documentation of XMLEtree,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) `findall()` only detects nodes that are **direct children** of the calling node.

`Invoice` is not a direct child of your `root` node. You are receiving `None`, because there are no children of the `root` node with a child named `Invoice`.

This is how your tree is structured:

```
<Root>
    <SourceDocuments>
        <SalesInvoices>
            <Invoice>
```

Your code is skipping SourceDocuments and SalesInvoices.

Try fixing it to something like this:

```py
for doc in root.findall('SourceDocuments'):
    for sales_invoice in doc.findall('SalesInvoices'):
        for invoice in sales_invoice.findall('Invoice'):
            for line in invoice.findall('Line'):
                for source2 in line.findall('ProductDescription'):
                    print(source2.text)
```

Comment: It is not true that `findall()` only can find nodes that are direct children of the calling node. That is a misunderstanding. I have pointed this out before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree/38971726#comment124248078_38971726

Answer (score 1):

For starters your xml contains a failed  closing tag at line 8

Secondly you can use namespace of your xml like this

```
ns = {'ns': 'urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Tax:PT_1.04_01'}
```

And then find the ProductDescription based on the namespace

```
for elem in root.findall('.//ns:Product', namespaces=nspace):
    desc = elem.find('ns:ProductDescription', namespaces=nspace)
    if desc is not None:
        print(desc.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `findall()` you get a list of the Elements. Findall can handle namespaces in my code abbr. with ns, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("example.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# search with xpath, findall() creates a list
ns = {node[0]: node[1] for _, node in ET.iterparse("example.xml", events=['start-ns'])}
prodDesc = root.findall(".//Invoice/Line/ProductDescription", ns)
# print first element in the list
print(prodDesc[0].text)
```

Output:
Your list contains only one element

```
Cachorro
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.
Ultimately, all your answers helped, and this code worked for me.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Parse XML into a Element Tree

tree= ET.parse ("2023_10_2023.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
#ET.dump(tree)

ns = {'ns': 'urn:OECD:StandardAuditFile-Tax:PT_1.04_01'}

#extract the productDescripton 
for doc in root.findall('.//ns:SourceDocuments',ns):
    for sales_invoice in doc.findall('.//ns:SalesInvoices',ns):
        for invoice in sales_invoice.findall('.//ns:Invoice',ns):
            for line in invoice.findall('.//ns:Line',ns):
                for source2 in line.findall('.//ns:ProductDescription',ns):
                    print(source2.text)
```